# Embedded youtube video not playing in landscape on iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, youtube, landscape, embedded-video

I'm trying to embed a youtube video in my app. It works fine but starts in portrait and will not rotate to landscape (making the video kind of small).

I'm doing all this in a UIWebView with the size of 237x353
The containing viewcontroller should only work in portrait (does this affect the issue).
I've read that embedded youtube videos automagically starts in a MPMoviePlayerController so I'm guessing it can control orientation on it's own?

Any clues on why it will not start in landscape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind. I figured the problem lies in using the `<iframe>` tag suggested by YouTube. This always made my video show in portrait. If your underlying viewcontroller only supports portrait that's what you going to get. You are better off using:

```
<embed id="yt" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZflCTKggPAQ" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="237" height="250"></embed>
```

Also what made this even harder to debug is the fact that the above code will not work in simulator whereas the `<iframe>` does. With the above code and device all is golden.

Comment: I don't understand -- what is the fix? (I have the reverse problem -- I'm launching YouTube from a UIWebView and it always comes up in landscape mode.)

Comment: @DavidMoles. One important word in sebrock's answer was invisible. I have since edited to make it visible, so perhaps this will make more sense to you now.

Comment: @TRiG -- It's more than two years since I posted the comment, so I have no idea what you changed?

Comment: @DavidMoles. If you click on the "edited 16 hours ago" link, you'll see the changes. The first occurrence of `<iframe>` in the answer was invisible, because it wasn't marked as a code item. I made it visible, and did a couple of other changes too.